# ElasticSearch Painless Scripts: Replace all fields except one

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents that it might have a variable number of fields, I know that it sill contain a customID, and I would like to replace all the fields except my customID by using the _update_by_query API

Initial Document

```
{
   customID : “123”,
   field1 : ”a”,
   field2 : “b”,
   field3 : “c”,
   ….

}
```

I want my target to be:

```
{
   customID : “123”,
   replaced: true     
}
```

Regardless of the number of extra fields available in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
POST test/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "def customID = ctx._source.customID; ctx._source.clear(); ctx._source = ['customID': customID, 'replaced': true]",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```